# Merge Two Data Sets PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge, json

Initially my script is fetching and decoding JSON according to some certain parameters placed in the URL, these values are then inserted into an array and re-encoded as JSON. I have to make two separate requests, one to facebook and one two instagram, and merge the output data. My problem is the two arrays don't seem to merge and just output the last data set in the array_merge function.

```
$igjsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($igurl)));
$fbjsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($fburl)));

$igresponse = array();
$igresponse["data"] = array();
foreach ($igjsonData->data as $igkey=>$igvalue) {            

        $igdata = array();
        $igdata["network"] = "instagramicon.png";
        $igdata["createdtime"] = $igvalue->caption->created_time;
        $igdata["username"] = $igvalue->caption->from->username;
        $igdata["profileimage"] = $igvalue->caption->from->profile_picture;
        $igdata["caption"] = $igvalue->caption->text;
        $igdata["postimage"] = $igvalue->images->standard_resolution->url;

        array_push($igresponse["data"], $igdata);
}

$fbresponse = array();
$fbresponse["data"] = array();
foreach ($fbjsonData->data as $fbkey=>$fbvalue) {            

        $fbdata = array();
        $fbdata["createdtime"] = $fbvalue->created_time;
        $fbdata["username"] = $fbvalue->from->name;        
        $data["profileimage"] = "profile_picture";
        $fbdata["caption"] = $fbvalue->message;
        $data["postimage"] = "postimage";

        array_push($fbresponse["data"], $fbdata);
}

$output = array_merge($igresponse, $fbresponse);
echo $output;
```

I need to either merge the data after it has been re-encoded as JSON, or merge them as arrays, before the re-encode, i'd like to be able to arrange the data in order of createdtime, if anyone know's how to do that too. Not too sure what the problem here actually is.

I've partially got it working, using the the 'array' function instead, however would still like to know how to organise by createdtime in my new array.

```
$output["data"] = array_merge($igresponse, $fbresponse);
$array = $output["data"];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it as shown below using the following code:

```
$igfbarray = array_merge($igresponse, $fbresponse);

$sortArray = array(); 

foreach($igfbarray as $created){ 
    foreach($created as $key=>$value){ 
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
            $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
        } 
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value; 
    } 
} 

$orderby = "createdtime"; //array key 

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_DESC,$igfbarray); 

$output["data"] = $igfbarray;

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same keys for both your arrays and as mentioned on the site http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php, the newest array will replace the previous one then.

The solution is probally to change the key "data" for the sencond array if you want the instagram data in a different element. Or you can use array_merge_recursive(). If you want the facebook data and the instagram data in the same element you have to rename all keys in the second array.

I used this example for exprimenting: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bkc-t76